# Get area between pixel wise masks and WSI patches

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

So basically I have a WSI (Whole slide image) which looks like this:

[image]

And I have a png mask which looks like this:

[image]

along with its position on the WSI (x: 1098,y: 2116, width: 167, height: 378)

Now what I want to do is to take the WSI, create patches of dimension 96x96 out of the WSI and for each of these patches I want to check if the white area under the mask file is present in at least 2/3 of the created patch.
For instance here is my pseudo code to create the patches:

```
self.crop_size = 96
is_fit = False
while True:
    patch_x = 0
    while True:
        patches.append((patch_x, patch_y, self.crop_size, self.crop_size, is_fit))
        if patch_x + self.crop_size > width:
            patch_x = width - self.crop_size
            patches.append((patch_x, patch_y, self.crop_size, self.crop_size, is_fit))
            break
        else:
            patch_x += self.crop_size
    if patch_y + self.crop_size > height:
        patch_y = height - self.crop_size
        patches.append((patch_x, patch_y, self.crop_size, self.crop_size, is_fit))
        break
    else:
        patch_y += self.crop_size
```

Now for each patch (I consider a patch the tuple I insert in `patches.append()`) I want to be able to set `True` to `is_fit` if at least 2/3 of the white area of the mask is present in the patch. 
Note that here I'm authorized to open the mask file from the code but not the WSI as it will eat up too much memory.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the following algorithm:

- For each patch `(x, y, width, height)` in the WSI, compute its coordinates relative to the mask position: `(x2, y2, width2, height2)`. There are some calculations to do here with `min` and `max` but nothing impossible.
- For each patch, compute the ratio `cv2.countNonZero(mask[y2:y2+height2, x2:x2 + width2]) / (self.crop_size * self.crop_size)`. If this ratio is above 2/3, then you can set your patch as `isFit = True`.

To get the position of the patch in the mask, let's assume that the mask is a rectangle with coordinates `(x_m, y_m, width_m, height_m)` in the WSI.
Then a patch `(x, y, width, height)` will have the following coordinates in the mask:

- `x2 = max(x - x_m, 0)` This value can be higher than `width_m` in which case you ignore the patch as it is completely outside the mask.
- `y2 = max(y - y_m, 0)` This value can be higher than `height_m` in which case you ignore the patch as it is completely outside the mask.
- `width2 = min(self.crop_size, width_m - x2)`
- `height2 = min(self.crop_size, height_m - y2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help, I think this is the right way to achieve what I want.
But here I'm struggling to get the absolute position right:

Comment: Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/EKami/1cdc53877efc79c77d6388b8c3f3ac53
It seems simple but I'm really not at ease with numbers :( . Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: @E-Kami I edited my answer to show the calculations for the coordinates of the patch in the mask.